# Getting 2 last elements of a url address

Tags: php, offset, explode

I'm trying to reach only the the site name and the domain, for example in case of images.google.com/thisIsJustAnExample it will return google.com.
this is what I tried to do,

```
  $url = 'https://images.google.com/thisIsJustAnExample';
  $zobrazeni = array();
  $zobrazeni = parse_url($url);
  $zobrazeni["host"] = explode(".", $zobrazeni["host"]);
  $zobrazeni["host"] = $zobrazeni["host"][count($zobrazeni["host"])-2] .".". $zobrazeni["host"][count($zobrazni["host"])-1];
```

---

And this is the Error I get:

**Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\retezce.php on line 25**

**Notice: Undefined variable: zobrazni in C:\xampp\htdocs\retezce.php on line 25**

**Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\retezce.php on line 25**

Comment: ,what do you mean by last two element in google.com?

Comment: If I have url: https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Db4zVdPMGcag8wfm3oGQAQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=fddg 
I want to get google.com

Comment: @ Mark,`parse_url` do not handle subdomains, for your scenario you can use Purl see here https://github.com/jwage/purl

Comment: What you're after are the `domain` and the `top-level-domain` of the web address. What do you want to get for a `xxx.co.uk` address? `xxx` and `co.uk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but one would be:

```
  $url = 'https://images.google.com/thisIsJustAnExample';
  $zobrazeni = array();
  $zobrazeni = parse_url($url);
  $zobrazeni = explode(".", $zobrazeni["host"]);
  $zobrazeni =  array_reverse($zobrazeni);
  $zobrazeni = $zobrazeni[1] . ' .' . $zobrazeni[0];
```

Or you could get the length of the array and use that instead of trying to subtract 2.

Comment: Thx a lot. Easy and simple.

Answer (score 1):

just play with this code, it should print "google"."com" if thats what you meant.
just remember that `count($verb)` (in case `$verb` is `array`) will return the number of the objects in the array.

```
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731201/getting-2-last-elements-of-a-url-address/29731258#29731258";
$verbs = explode('.', $url);

$domainName = explode('/', $verbs[count($verbs)-2]);
$domainExt = explode('/', $verbs[count($verbs)-1]);

echo $domainName[2] . "." . $domainExt[0];
```

Comment: This looks promising but the result from "http://images.google.com/thisIsJustAnExample"
is "google.com/thisIsJustAnExample"

Comment: Awesome! Last problem is with longer links. "http://" also appears in the link. I tried copying URL of this site stackoverflow.com/question.... and the result was "http:// stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Thanks Danny, It works but there are some problems with it when I tried complicated urls.